# Apply a not null constraint via a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to make sure that every project in my database has a contact person.  "projects" and "contacts" have a many-to-many relationship, specified in the table "projects_contacts".  Could I create a table constraint within projects that will specify the project must exist within the join table?  Or do I need to take a completely different approach?
(I need users to be able to manually enter contact data while in the middle of adding project data, so I'm worried that the NOT NULL will hang up their ability to create a project before there is a contact.)

Would this be better addressed in the build of the user interface?

Thanks!

```
CREATE TABLE projects(
id_project INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
description text)

CREATE TABLE contacts(
id_contact integer PRIMARY KEY
firstname varchar(100) )

CREATE TABLE projects_contacts(
id_projects_contacts integer PRIMARY KEY,>
id_project integer,
id_contact integer
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY project_fkey (id_project) REFERENCES projects ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY contact_fkey (id_contact) REFERENCES contacts ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Comment: For users who access the database via the web, adding one project at a time, I will use Bill's tip: "Therefore most you can defer a constraint is until commit: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-set-constraints.html"

Comment: For administrators, who need to either add one project at a time OR import large datasets, I will have to think through whether I need a NOT NULL constraint in the projects_contacts join table.

Comment: With the NOT NULL constraint, administrators will be hampered in their options for crosswalking data into our database.  However, without the NOT NULL constraint, administrators will need to know to double check that all projects have contacts (and that there are no contacts without projects)- after the crosswalk. Or... I could write a script for them to run that does the checking?

Answer (score 1):

The only way you could implement this with a table-level constraint is for `projects` to contain a non-nullable foreign key reference to any entry in `projects_contacts`.
But this would be a circular reference, since `projects_contacts` also depends on `projects.

You said you don't want to force users to enter a contact while they're still creating a project, so basically you can't constrain a project with a non-nullable reference like that.

There is no constraint that means "I need this to be non-null, but later." It's in the definition of any constraint that it must be satisfied by the time you end the transaction.

Therefore most you can defer a constraint is until commit:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-set-constraints.html

I assume you will need the deferral to be longer than the length of one transaction.

So ultimately, these types of custom business rules end up being enforced by application code that you have to develop.

Answer (score 1):

If including a contact on the project is mandatory, then your GUI should not send an add request unless the contact data (or key if already exists) is part of the transaction.

This way, you don't need the FK to allow nulls.

However, from business standpoint, what would you do when a contact is no longer a contact for the project and no substitute contact has been assigned?

In this case, your business should make the decision. If so, the FK has to allow nulls on update.

To combine both cases, your FK should allow nulls but your business layer should not accept create project transaction with null contact fk.

You also need to think about this business question: Could a contact exist without a project? The answer is important in your GUI design.

As per your statement "I need users to be able to manually enter contact data while in the middle of adding project data" - This makes sense to me only if the contacts would be directly added to the current project, but what if the user starts creating a project, create a contact then abandons the process of creating the project? How would you identify the added contact? So, may be you want to refine this requirement.